# help with poisson

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Call centre incoming calls are randomly distributed following poisson distribution with an average rate of 12 per hour. Calculate the probability that for seven one hour periods there will be one hour with no calls, three hours with one call and three hours with 2 or more calls.

I used f(0)={mu^0 (e)^-mu]/0! for no calls and then similarly for one call f(1) to the power of 3 as there are 3 hours and also for the last part but the answer is not the same

Comment: Hi and welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use poisson for no calls, one call and 2 or more calls for the weeks:

Comment: I used f(0)={mu^0 (e)^-mu]/0! for no calls and then similarly for one call f(1) to the power of 3 as there are 3 hours and also for the last part but the answer is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the probability for $0$ calls, $1$ call, and more than one call in an hour, say these are $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$ respectively, you are halfway done.

Then you have to choose one of the seven hours to receive no calls ($7$ ways);

And choose $3$ of the remaining $6$ hours to receive $1$ call (${6\choose 3}$ ways);

That leaves the remaining three hours for more than one call each.

Then your desired probability is $7\cdot{6\choose 3}\cdot p_0\cdot p_1^3\cdot p_2^3$.

Comment: In a poisson process don't you think there is a difference in calculating the probability of random sucesses in an one hour interval and a three hour interval.  I understood the problem differently as three parts and I looked at your solution and withdrew it.  Still it kept itching me that the probability that you will no calls in three hours is not the same as cube of the probability that you will no calls in one hour.  correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I understood the problem to refer to $7$ separate one-hour periods.  In fact I think the probability of no calls in one three hour period (Poisson, $36$) is the same as the cube of the probability of no calls in one hour (Poisson, $12$), since $e^{-36}=\left(e^{-12}\right)^3$.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan How would you solve this problem?

Comment: @paw88789 it is a very small number. In your first sentence do you mean to say that we should just calculate the probability of 1 call in 1 hour only?